# Why does my program crash when defining the two big arrays?

Tags: c

I currently have the following code:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000000
#define CHILDS 2

typedef struct
{
    char a[20];
    int b;
} shared_data_type;

int main()
{
    int i;

    // I need 2 arrays and 1 variable of this type
    shared_data_type v1[ARRAY_SIZE], v2[ARRAY_SIZE], aux;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        strcpy(v1[i].a, "RANDOM STRING");
        v1[i].b = rand() % 50;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But if I run the program with this line of code: `shared_data_type v1[ARRAY_SIZE], v2[ARRAY_SIZE], aux;` I get this error in the output: `make: *** [run] Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `ARRAY_SIZE` ? If it's huge, there might be not enough stack memory for `v1` and `v2`

Comment: You should remove the definitions of `fd`, `p1`, `p2`, `p_inicio`, `p_fim`, `m_inicio`, `m_fim`, `v2` and `aux` since they're not relevant to your problem, being unused variables.

Comment: @Renat that was the problem. ARRAY_SIZE was 1.000.000, lowered it to 100 and it worked perfectly. Thanks mate|

Comment: @JonathanLeffler they had relevance for the rest of the program, I forgot to take them out in this question but they are being used for things that the program computs. Thanks!

Comment: If the definitions of `v1` and `v2` cause the crash, the probability is that you've tried to create variables too large for the stack.  Your structure is 24 bytes.  If you're on Windows, you have a 1 MiB stack; on Unix-like systems, you usually get 8 MiB stack.  You can fit a little under 350,000 of those structures on the Unix stack, so if `ARRAY_SIZE` is larger than about 174,000, you're going to crash on Unix.  On Windows, if `ARRAY_SIZE` is larger than about 21,800, you're going to crash.  Treat my calculations with a small pinch of salt — but the value of `ARRAY_SIZE` is crucial.

Comment: We're uninterested in the rest of your program.  Please learn about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  I accept that `v2` is relevant to the crash — it occupies as much space as `v1` and contributes to the stack overflow.  The others are barely a factor in it (they use a minuscule amount of memory by comparison with the arrays).

Comment: If `ARRAY_SIZE` needs to be 1,000,000, you will have to use dynamic memory allocation (or file scope — global — variable definitions) to get around the limit of the stack size in your program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler tahnks for your comments. I am not authorized to use dynamic memory allocation in this program yet so I posted the answer that I could get from my teachers. Plus I read all your comments and got more knowledge from your suggestions! Thanks a lot, in the future I will keep my questions clean.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler also I edited my code and removed unsued variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try allocating the arrays in the system memory rather than the stack of the process:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000000
#define CHILDS 2

typedef struct
{
    char a[20];
    int b;
} shared_data_type;

int main()
{
    int i;

    // I need 2 arrays and 1 variable of this type
    shared_data_type * v1, * v2, aux;

    v1 = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(*v1);
    v2 = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(*v2);

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        strcpy(v1[i].a, "RANDOM STRING");
        v1[i].b = rand() % 50;
    }

    return 0;
}
```